# Creating Columns in HTML Table Body Email with VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, html-table, html-email

I have created a table that will be placed in the body of an Outlook email in HTML format. I am struggling to place the values into proper columns. I have been playing around with "td" tags, but unsuccessful. All the values are now next to each other without spaces between them and therefore not in proper table format. Please help!

My code:

```
Public Sub HypMail4()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String

Set Out App = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strbody = ""
strbody = strbody & _
"<html>" & "<table>" & "<font color = ""red""><b>" & Range("A1") & 
Range("B1") & Range("C1") & Range("D1") & Range("E1") & "</font></b>" & " 
</th>" & _
"<tr>" & Range("A2") & Range("B2") & Range("C2") & Range("D2") & Range("E2") 
 & "</tr>"
strbody = strbody & _
"<tr>" & Range("A3") & Range("B3") & Range("C3") & Range("D3") & Range("E3") 
& "</tr>"
strbody = strbody & _
"<tr>" & Range("A4") & Range("B4") & Range("C4") & Range("D4") & Range("E4") 
& "</tr>" & "</table>" & "</html>"

On Error Resume Next

With OutMail
    .To = "zzz@example.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Test"
    .HTMLBody = strbody
    .Send
End With

On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: there are no `<td>` tags in your code. You should read how the correct syntax of a HTML table is: [w3schools.com: HTML Tables](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp). Also remove `On Error Resume Next` or you will never notice when an error occurs. This line just hides all error messages but the errors still occur.

Comment: I have attempted to place td tags, however it seems to mess up the output. Any advice what should have td and what shouldn't? Also where to exactly place them? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to answer my question myself by indeed including td tags. The main problem, however, was that I defined strbody too many times which messed up the table format (hence td tags weren't working) - please see code below:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "<html>" & "<table>" & "<tr>" & "<td>" & Range("A1") & "</td>" & "<td>" & Range("B1") & "</td>" & "<td>" & Range("C1") & "</td>" & "</tr>" & _
     "<tr>" & "<td>" & Range("A2") & "</td>" & "<td>" & Range("B2") & "</td>" & "<td>" & Range("C2") & "</td>" & "</tr>" & _
     "<tr>" & "<td>" & Range("A3") & "</td>" & "<td>" & Range("B3") & "</td>" & "<td>" & Range("C3") & "</td>" & "</tr>" & _
     "<tr>" & "<td>" & Range("A4") & "</td>" & "<td>" & Range("B4") & "</td>" & "<td>" & Range("C4") & "</td>" & "</tr>" & "</table>" & "</html>"

    With OutMail
        .To = "zzz.com@zzz.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Test"
        .HTMLBody = strbody
        .Send
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that you can reduce it to `strbody = "<html><table><tr><td>" & Range("A1") & "</td><td>" & Range("B1") & "</td><td>" & Range("C1") & "</td></tr>" &  "<tr><td>" & Range("A2") & "</td><td>" & Range("B2") & "</td><td>" & Range("C2") & "</td></tr>" &  "<tr><td>" & Range("A3") & "</td><td>" & Range("B3") & "</td><td>" & Range("C3") & "</td></tr>" & "<tr><td>" & Range("A4") & "</td><td>" & Range("B4") & "</td><td>" & Range("C4") & "</td></tr></table></html>"` which makes it a bit simpler.